# WP_Query to filter specific parent Custom Post Type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have 2 custom post types created via theme, `rt_book` and `rt_chapter`. Each `rt_book` has several `rt_chapter` posts. When I use `single-rt_book.php` (which should show the contents of a specific `rt_book` post), how can I filter only the `rt_chapter` belongs to that specific `rt_book` being loaded?

My current `WP_Query` is as follow (which returns all `rt_chapter`):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'rt_chapter', // TODO: Filter specific book.
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $posts[] = $query->post;
    }
}
```

---

I relate these two custom post types by setting the Post Meta of `rt_book` with an array of `rt_chapter` post IDs, via function `add_post_meta({post ID of rt_book}, 'chapter_orders', {post ID of rt_chapter})` and `update_post_meta()`.

Tried `child_of` option of `WP_Query`, but does not affect the results.

Comment: Need more info : How you are `rt_chapter` belongs to `rt_books` while creating `rt_chapter`.

Comment: Try using taxonomy parameters in query. [More here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
$args = array(
 'post_type'         => 'rt_chapter', 
 'post_status'       => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page'    => -1,
 'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
 'orderby'           => 'date',
 'order'             => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
     array(
         'key'    => 'rt_book',
         'value'  => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'chapter_orders', true),
         'compare'=> 'IN'
     ),
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) {
 while($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $posts[] = $query->post;
 }
}
```

Comment: I was just trying the same too. However, no posts are returned. However, when I use `$post_ids = explode(',', get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'chapter_orders', true)); wp_reset_query();` and use `'post__in' => $post_ids,` in `WP_Query()` , correct posts appear. Why ?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think wordpress default `WP_Query()` is executing son new instance of `WP_Query()` may conflict each other. However you got your solution, you can check test with `get_posts()` in place of `WP_Query()` may work in your case.

Comment: Excellent. The final solution is: `$post_ids = explode(',', get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'chapter_orders', true));
$posts = get_posts(array('post__in' => $post_ids, 'post_type' => 'rt_chapter'));`. Just 2 lines. Thanks for your hint & help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hopefully this should work.

```
$tax_slug = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'rt_chapter', // TODO: Filter specific book.
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'rt_book',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tax_slug
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Does this work even I save the information in Post Meta of `rt_book` ?

Comment: In that case you will need to use `meta_query` parameter.

Comment: nice hint. I just tried to use `meta_query` parameter, it returns nothing. However, I tried to use `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'chapter_orders', true)` to obtain the `rt_chapter` IDs, it returns a list of IDs.